# How do I delete these 3 extra font glyphs? FontForge seems to be adding them after save

Tags: fonts, font-design, web-fonts, font-forge

In FontForge, I cannot delete these 3 glyphs no matter what I try.

[image: FontForge]

The glyph info on each is:

1. 104 (0x68) U+???? ".notdef"
2. 105 (0x69) U+???? "glyph1"
3. 106 (0x6a) U+???? "glyph2"

I keep deleting them `(Encoding > Detach & Remove Glyphs)`, then save  the font as a .woff or .woff2 `(File > Generate Fonts)`, but every time I open the new output file the glyphs are still there.

Seems like FontForge is adding them back.

I've spent a few hours going over settings, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fontTools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) has a program specifically designed for this task called [*subset*](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subset/). Unfortunately I had to learn the hard way that subsetting with FontForge isn't ideal, but it was almost too easy with `pyftsubset`.

```
pyftsubset "input.ttf" \
    --flavor="woff" \
    --output-file="output.woff"  \
    --layout-features="[PICK-EM]" \
    --unicodes="[PICK-EM]" \
    --with-zopfli \
    --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Notdef is a [fallback glyph](https://www.figma.com/blog/when-fonts-fall/) that signifies you've typed a character that the font doesn't include. You definitely don't want to remove that glyph, text would display wrongly without it.

I believe FontForge may automatically build one into every font created using it to make sure one is included; certainly another font editor called Glyphs does. You can see discussion of this [on this forum](https://typedrawers.com/discussion/2690/pet-peeve-empty-notdef-character/p1).

Comment: Thanks, yes I understand the purpose of `U+0000`. I want the glyph gone. Messing around with fontTools now as it seems to be better for subsetting a font.